# Using decompression library in AS3 via FlasCC

Tags: c++, c, actionscript-3, compression, flascc

I have an AS3 AIR project in which I need to decompress files using a specific decompression method. Apparently the code for this is found [here, in the contrib/blast directory of the zlib distribution](https://github.com/madler/zlib/tree/master/contrib/blast). I would port this to AS3 manually, however I'm practically illiterate in C/C++ and don't have much experience in coding compression/decompression algorithms either.

I discovered FlasCC, and decided to download it and see if it works. The hello world sample worked well and everything. I looked up how to compile SWCs, since I figured that would be a good form to use it in, and attempted to compile it. Unfortunately it didn't work.

This is what I write:

```
$ "/cygdrive/f/C2F/FlasCC/sdk/usr/bin/gcc" blast.c -emit-swc=blast -o blast.swc
```

And this is what I get:

```
/cygdrive/f/C2F/FlasCC/sdk/usr/bin/../../usr/lib/stdlibs_abc/crt1_c.o: error: un
defined reference to '_main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I mentioned I'm completely useless at C, and this is the first time I've used FlasCC. If anybody could tell me what I'm doing wrong, or even just provide an alternative, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to look into the examples of Flascc. I think you have to provide a symbol file (`.txt`) that the compiler should not optimize.

Answer (score 2):

swc requires a main entry point.. 
add:

```
int main() 
{ 
    AS3_GoAsync();
}
```

Comment: When I paste in that code, I now get: `/tmp/cc3Ol8dV.o: error: undefined reference to '_AS3_GoAsync'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`. I'm sorry, I really am useless at this. Am I supposed to be better experienced with C to use FlasCC?

Comment: Well I figured that I had to include AS3.h and it finally compiled. I can't seem to use it properly in AS3 though. I'll see if the SWC sample helps though.